# golang syntax error: unexpected in struct

Tags: go

```
type WebServer struct {
    TodoService      task.TodoService
    UserService      usr.UserService
    SessionService   session.Service
    CategoryService  task.CategoryService
    WorkerService    task.WorkerService
    ApiWorkerService task.ApiWorkerService
    BlacklistService task.BlacklistService
    LabelService     *labels.Service
    StatusService    *statuses.Service
    InviteService    *invites.Service
    Runner           *task.Runner
    TaskForIP        make(map[string]int)
    Params           WebServerParams
}
```

this is my current code, is not my application, and return this error :

```
app\infrastructure\web\webserver.go:41:23: syntax error: unexpected (, expecting
 semicolon or newline or }
```

the line 41 is the line TaskForIP, i can't remove make because is necesary in application, how i can fix ?

Comment: just remove the make(), this is a struct declaration, you can't initialize values in it.

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer yes i did this, but application need to be channel this funnction, return this error after """assignment to entry in nil map"""

Comment: Initialize the map field in the constructor then ?

Answer (score 1):

Replace

`TaskForIP        make(map[string]int)`

To

`TaskForIP        map[string]int`

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
)

type WebServer struct {
    TodoService      task.TodoService
    UserService      usr.UserService
    SessionService   session.Service
    CategoryService  task.CategoryService
    WorkerService    task.WorkerService
    ApiWorkerService task.ApiWorkerService
    BlacklistService task.BlacklistService
    LabelService     *labels.Service
    StatusService    *statuses.Service
    InviteService    *invites.Service
    Runner           *task.Runner
    TaskForIP        map[string]int
    Params           WebServerParams
}

func (ws WebServer) NewInstance() WebServer {
    ws.TaskForIP = make(map[string]int)
    return ws
}

func main() {
    webServer := WebServer{}.NewInstance()
    log.Println(webServer)
}
```